# Filter Values in Groovy List

Tags: groovy

I have a list like below:

```
def array = '''\
\SYN_1_M1, SYN_2_M1, SYN_3_M1\,
\SYN_1_M2, SYN_2_M2, SYN_3_M2\
'''
```

I want to filter all values in list which start with `=~ ^SYN_3*` and then import to another list. I write like this:

```
array.find{ it.contains("/^SYN_3_*/") }
```

But it seen not correct, can s/o help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need

```
array.findAll { it.startsWith("SYN_3_") }
```